Swipe through fragments in Navigation Drawer Views Activity
I can't get the swipe between fragments to work without recreating everything new.
I go to Android Studio and create a new project “Navigation Drawer Views Activity” Language Kotlin. This is what i would like to use as Base, now add the "Swipe" functionallity.
This is my first Kotlin Project, in the past i used Java.
All the tutorials are using other ways to go to the fragments and i end up in kicking out what Android Studio has prepared.
So can somebody give me a hand or prepare the neccessary changes so that i can do it step by step.
Regards
and a happy new year
Robert
